# Problem: - Material Design is not showing on my Mobile

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am using Material Design for Android, it is working fine on emulator but when I m installing it on my phone it is not working/ it is not showing.

**Dependency I m using**

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

**My XML fILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context=".SetUpProfileActivity">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="159dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="138dp"
    android:src="@drawable/user"
    app:civ_border_color="#7E7B7B"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="Enter Your Details Here"
    android:textColor="#535252"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:hint="Enter your Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout3"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:prefixText="+91"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout2">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Phone"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout4"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout3">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout5"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout4">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/reddark"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Update"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:cornerRadius="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout5" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

**theme.xml content**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.Backsoon" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/reddark</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">#323232</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">#303030</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

**Image of Emulator Pixel 5 API 27**
[image]

**On phone, they are showing only when I m clicking on designs**
Image of my fone
[image]
[image]

Comment: Add the contents of the themes.xml file

Comment: I have added please check sir.

Comment: Please add the full code for the design with root layout .

Comment: Sir sorry but what is root layout?

Comment: I mean the entire contents of the design file

Comment: I have added entire code of desing file please check

Comment: There is no problem with the design code. I tested it and it works fine

Comment: yes sir it is working fine on my emulator also but when I open/install the app on my mobile then it is not working properly that is the case. i have attached the photos

Comment: Yes, I tested it on a real device and there is no problem with it either :) . Are you using a custom theme on your phone? Try the default theme

Comment: oh sir, now I changed my theme from dark mode to light mode and now it is working but why it is not showing on the dark mode then??

Comment: There is another file to set a different theme when activating the night mode on the phone https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme